# Mime types for uploading pdf in PHP in different browsers

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am creating an web application that allows users to upload pdf documents.  The following is the code to check(Restrict) the document type to pdf.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {
  $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
  $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
  $size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
  $tmpname = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
  $ext = substr($name, strrpos($name,'.'));  //Get the extension of the selected file
  echo $type.' This is the type';
  echo '<br>';
  if (($type == "application/pdf")||($type == "application/octet-streamn")) {
    echo 'ok';
  } else {
    echo "That is not a pdf document";
  }
}
```

I checked the types by echo(ing) $type to the screen.  But the type output is different for firefox.  I just need to confirm the following mime types.  Am I correct when I say:

> Internet explorer : application/pdf
>
> Opera: application/pdf
>
> FireFox : application/octet-streamn

or is there a standard mime type that covers all existing browsers.  Please help, I am still getting my feed wet with php and files

Comment: You can't know what the file really is if you rely on the mime-type. Anyone can send a .php file and fake it's image/gif or similar. That's why we don't trust user input, and file upload is user input.

Comment: **Do not trust anything sent from the user**. It would be super simple to send a PHP file with the mime type `application/pdf`.

Comment: The output I get if I use application/pdf only for checking file type says it not a pdf on firefox. is there a work around it ? because I dont think I can exclude file checking for pdf's on firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't trust `$_FILES['myfile']['type']` as it is provided by the client. A better solution is to use [finfo_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php):

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
if($type == 'application/pdf'){
    //Is a PDF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, and browser issues use JQuery

```
var filename="";
$('#upload').on( 'change', function() {
filename= $( this ).val();
var exten = filename.split('.').pop();
if(exten!="pdf"){
    alert("Only pdf documents are allowed");
    $(this).val('');
}
});
```